# What can I change from this Machine Learning script written on Python? I need to fill my missing rainfall data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing hydrological modeling on HEC-HMS, for that I need daily rainfall data, there is 3 weather stations nearby the studied basin, 2 of them have a full record from 2005 to 2020, and 1 of then has plenty of missing values, so I'm thinking about using this [script](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/fill-missing-precipitation-data-with-artificial-intelligence-python-keras-tutorial) to fill those missing values, so far I've tried just changing the data and the definition of the train sets but I hasn't worked so far. Why I'm getting NaN values from the model.predict() function and what do I need to change in order to fill my missing data? I'm trying to fill Weather station 1 (Estación 1 or Est1) with Est2 and Est3. This is what I've done so far:

> Importing data

```
get_ipython().magic('pylab inline')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
TodasEstaciones = pd.read_csv('Est1_Est2_Est3Completos.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
TodasEstaciones.head()
```

The data I'm using can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjQM47SxsdRJhYoXkhx_xxwXqbmT9Q?e=YB1EY8)

> Plotting full dataset

```
TodasEstaciones.loc['2005-05-01':'2020-05-05'].plot(subplots=True, figsize=(12, 8)); plt.legend(loc='best')
xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

> Import date/time

```
import datetime
#we create a date column to extract the week number
TodasEstaciones['date']=TodasEstaciones.index
#apply a lambda function to the whole panda dataframe column
TodasEstaciones['week'] = TodasEstaciones['date'].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])
#drop the date column because we dont need it
del TodasEstaciones['date']
#let see our dataframe
TodasEstaciones.head()
```

> Defining training sets

```
#Definition of training sets
X_train = TodasEstaciones.loc['2016-01-01':'2016-03-02',['Est2','Est3','week']].astype(float32).values#,'week']] # Est 2, 3 and #week
y_train = TodasEstaciones.loc['2016-01-01':'2016-03-02','Est1'].astype(float32).values # Est 1

# Import `StandardScaler` from `sklearn.preprocessing`
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Define the scaler 
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)

# Scale the train set
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)

X_train[:20]
```

> Defining the model (this is where I'm getting the NaN values)

```
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(12, activation='linear', input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
                   
model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=200,verbose=0)

y_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_pred[:10]
```

> The rest of the code

```
plot(TodasEstaciones.loc['2011-05-01':'2016-08-02'].index,y_pred,label='Predicted')
TodasEstaciones['Est1'].loc['2011-05-01':'2016-08-02'].plot()
figsize(12,8)
ylim(0,40)
legend(loc='best')

#Get the prediction for the train set
X_missing = TodasEstaciones.loc['2011-05-01':'2016-08-02',['Est2','Est3','week']].astype(float32).values

# Import `StandardScaler` from `sklearn.preprocessing`
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Define the scaler 
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_missing)

# Scale the train set
X_missing = scaler.transform(X_missing)

y_missing = model.predict(X_missing)
y_missing = y_missing.reshape([50]).tolist()

TodasEstaciones['Est1_Completed']=TodasEstaciones['Est1']
TodasEstaciones['Est1_Completed'].loc['2011-05-01':'2016-08-02']=y_missing

TodasEstaciones.loc['22011-05-01':'2016-08-02',['Est1','Est1_Completed','Est2','Est3']].plot(subplots=True, 
                                                   figsize=(15, 10)); plt.legend(loc='best')
xticks(rotation='vertical')
ylim(0,50)
```

Comment: Whatever is your way of preprocessing the data, it is definitely not working. There are still some NaNs in the training data, either in X_train or y_train. Check them properly because the model definition seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you think I need to normalize the data before running the model? I just checked and there is none NaNs on the training data, just some missing values (blanks).

Comment: How are those blanks being handled? Are they None? This could be a problem for sure.

Comment: No, they are just blanks, I've checked the data of the example [link](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/fill-missing-precipitation-data-with-artificial-intelligence-python-keras-tutorial) and its pretty similar to the data I'm using, do I need to change the model or the train data if my data is slightly different than the example?